# which is the difference between magnetic flux and magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

greeting

confuses me  this definition of electromagnetic induction  .

Electromagnetic induction,
which states that whenever a conductor cuts through magnetic lines of
flux, a voltage is induced into the conductor.

Why flux rather than magnetic field flux has a different meaning

Comment: This question again. Nice.

Comment: Do some basic research, a Google search will give you lots of information.  Then if there are any specific questions come back and ask.